# Merge or ban howto and how-to tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

I see no reason to distinguish [howto](/questions/tagged/howto) and [how-to](/questions/tagged/how-to). They should be synonyms. There are already [2 votes to synonymize them](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/howto/synonyms), but it's a rarely-used tag, so it apparently doesn't get much attention.

Edit: comments also suggest we <s>ban</s> **burninate** these very vague tags. While arguably some questions could be "why" or "when", an extremely large portion could be labeled "how", rendering the labels meaningless.

Comment: Shouldn't these be banned instead?

Comment: I added howto to one of my questions and someone almost immediately removed it. Wouldn't hurt to ban, since they are rather vague I suppose.

Comment: These *definitely* should be banned. What possible purpose could they serve on a Q&A site? They're equivalent to a `question` tag. BURNINATE THEM!

Comment: Look at it this way: the "howto" tag is a good starting point for flagging, editing and retagging ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Personally I see no reason to keep tags that go against the whole purpose of a Q&A site.

Since `howto` or `how-to` usually translates into "*Do this for me!*" or "*Can some one guide me step by step to achieve this*", they with no doubt should be **burninate**!

**Take the very essence of `howto`:**

> Giving basic instructions to the layperson on how to do or make something.

This is not the purpose of a Q&A site, as stated by the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), where it read on the first paragraph:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

`howto` always ends up referring to a guidance on a broad subject, not to a practical problem at hand.

---

There are at this date 451 questions using the `howto` tag, and after some analysis to the existing questions, many of them have the title starting with "How to ...", but the question itself refers to a particular issue.

**e.g.,**

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10258076/352449) was tagged like:

```
javascript jquery internet-explorer bugs howto
```

Looking at these tags, having the `howto` present, I get the idea that this user wants to learn how to create bugs on internet-explorer using jQuery. Doesn't make any sense, the `howto` is just causing confusion!

**The question is titled:**

```
IE bug with global variables. How to bypass this bug?
```

Give a better clear idea that a bug exists and the user needs a solution to go around it.

So, **yes, please BURNINATE** this tag(s).